# Pass array in request to Laravel by delete method don't work

Tags: laravel

I passed array to Delete route in Laravel and then in this part of code

> foreach ($request->input('publicIds') as $node)
> print($node);

I got this error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file

Why the route didn't work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use a `$request->input()` in a `foreach()`, be sure to include a fallback if nothing is passed. If nothing is passed, `$request->input()` is `null`, and `foreach(null as $node)` is not valid.

If you add a fallback, it will use that instead (in your case, an array):

```
$request->input('publicIds')     // `null`
$request->input('publicIds', []) // `[]`
```

So, to make your code type-safe for a `foreach()`, do the following:

```php
foreach ($request->input('publicIds', []) as $node) {
  print($node);
}
```

In scenarios where `$request->input('publicIds')` is `null`, it will fallback to an array. If scenarios where `$request->input('publicIds')` is already an array, the fallback will be skipped (as it is already an array), and your code is now safe.